# Objective-C: How to convert json value to BOOL?

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a property on my `Model` as

```
@property (nonatomic) bool *groupOnly;
```

and my `JSON` from `API` looks like

```
{
            category =             {
                groupName = Technology;
                id = "b0bddf25-5cce-4184-a589-570fbd39a562";
                name = Software;
            };
            groupOnly = 0;
            recurring = 0;
        }
```

When I inspect the type of value for the boolean, I see that it is `_NSCFBoolean`

[image]
I want to store this information as boolean, so I tried

```
budgetCategoryModel.groupOnly = (bool *) [[[json valueForKey:@"groupOnly"] stringValue] isEqual:@"1"];
```

but what I get back is `nil`

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What is the recommended way to convert to boolean?

Comment: Get rid of the asterisk. `bool` is not an object type.

Comment: Also, `groupOnly` will be a number. Why convert and compare to a string?

Comment: Its a good point @rmaddy, I will made that change in my code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your model to declare a `bool` rather than a `bool` pointer:

```
@property (nonatomic) bool groupOnly;
```

Note the lack of a '*'.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean declaration in your model is incorrect. It should be

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL groupOnly;
```

and the way you should parse the boolean value from you web service response should be like below:

```
budgetCategoryModel.groupOnly = [[json valueForKey:@"groupOnly"] boolValue];
```

Hope this helps ..